# Is it possible to set a memory limit specifically to a variable?

Tags: php

Is it possible to set a memory limit specifically to a variable ?
(This limit would be of course useless if greater than the memory_limit in php.ini.)

I would like $foo to be always less big than 1mb for example, but don't care about other variables's size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to impose a size limit on variables in PHP.

Depending on what you want to do, you could build a class with a [setter function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) that checks the size before assigning a value to a variable of the class.

Comment: +1 - this is the same advice that i would have given based on the question

Answer (score 1):

What is $foo in your situation? If it is a string, you can do it with chars limit. If it is a number, you can check number size.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the idea of checking the number of characters of a string :
I can have the string representation of `$foo` with, for example, `print_r($foo,true)` and check the number of char.

```
if(strlen(print_r($foo,true))<10000){
  /*do something*/
};
```

(although this solution isn't to use as time and power consuming. And it's a really rough way to check the memory space needed).